# wordpress: can't get do_action to work with custom function

Tags: wordpress

I'm using woocommerce and on functions.php i've hooked my function to an action.

```
add_action('my_calculate_shipping','calculate_shipping_2');
function calculate_shipping_2() {

echo "test";


}
```

Now on `cart-shipping.php` i use `do_action('my_calculate_shipping');` and `test` isn't displayed.  I've used `function_exists` and it returns false.

How do i solve this?

Comment: What if you try to call `calculate_shipping_2()` directly in your template? Your current code should work...

Comment: That doesn't really explain why adding the action didn't work though...interesting.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm still wondering.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is plugins are loaded before theme,
Ref: [WordPress Code Flow](https://codex.wordpress.org/User:DavidHouse/Wordpress_Code_Flow)

You can wrap your `add_action` code in some hook which is called in upper level.